# "Top tags" look funny in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-profile, design

So I looked at my profile (for probably the first time) and see this:

[image: image of ugliness]

I see at least three things wrong with this:

1. The tag background box seems to have a max width, but the text doesn't care, and overflows it.
2. The tag boxes have two different border colours. (The Lego stud on the left is darker.)
3. The bronze badge doesn't use the site-specific badge icons.

Comment: I don't get #1 in google chrome (text truncated as "super-smash-br...").  Not sure about #2, but the shape is different for the team-fortress-2 tag.  I see the same for #3.  I used this link to compare: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/12939/toomai

Comment: This got marked as "completed" shortly before you commented. Things have indeed changed that fixed the first two issues, though perhaps not in the expected way (the text gets trunctated instead of the box width increasing).